# Next view loads before old view clears

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I've been having this strange problem from the beginning of the project until now. When clicking through pages, it seems as though the new (or 'next') page loads the view before the DOM is cleared. So it sometimes stacks elements from the next page under the old page, then after a slight delay the old page gets cleared.

For example, the first screenshot is the login page:

[image: Login page]

And the second screenshot is if you click to 'sign up'.

[image: Clicked sign up]

To clarify, this happens when loading pages too. For example I have links in a nav bar:

```
<a href="#/category/1">ONE</a>
<a href="#/category/2">TWO</a>
```

And clicking through those pages I see stacked dom elements. Is it cause of this "#" situation?

Comment: use `ng-hide` or `ng-if` as default and as soon as you reach then add `ng-show` to that particular **DOM**